# Where we can put sample input datas for unit testing in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am creating unit test for my angular application. I want to know **the better place** where we can store or configure datas like user name, password ..etc for unit testing.

```
it('loging with existing account', (done) => {
    authService.login('sahalXXX@gmail.com', 'secretPass')
        .subscribe(res => {
            expect(res).toBeTruthy();
            done();
        },
            err => {
                expect(err).toBeFalsy();
                done();
            });
});
```

Comment: If you want to save actual sensitive data in the code, then the answer is no place. No amount of obfuscation can hide your front-end code from being read by the end-user.

Comment: It is for unit test , this account will delete after each successful build